# SharePoint Development in a small firm

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, repository

We work for a small firm and we just started getting few SharePoint Projects.

**Setup what we have done:**

1. Purchased a new server and installed SharePoint 2010, SQL 2008R2, Visual Studio 2010 in the same server.
2. Created the application in the SharePoint Central Administration.
3. Developers directly login to server built the project using Visual Studio. (In server, only 2 ppl can login and work)

**Issue:**
1. We started getting 2 more projects, and the count of developers became more.

> We need to know how to set up an environment where all the developers can work.
>   Also need to know if there is any way that they can work from local and then we can push the application to the server.
>   We do not have budget to get one more server and install TFS, so need to know if there is any other repository where we can make the above task possible.
>   Any help from all you people will me greatful.

Expecting a reply at the earliest.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what specification laptops/PC's you have you may be able to create a virtual machine to do the development within. All the licenses here would be covered by MSDN subscription(if your devs have this) I think. VM's can get very big so what all the developers did in my last company was to have an external HD with our VM's on there, i think we were using e-sata connected external hd's
If you have TFS you should be able to connect the VM's up to this which essentially would allow you to use the build functionality to create your WSP packages ready for production(once testing has passed on your VM obviously), this package can then be dropped by TFS automatically to your production server ready for installation.

The great thing about this model is that you can have multiple VM's so if you break one you can just use a fresh one! All developers will be on a different VM but with some configuration would be working from the same source code.

Essentially this method has it's drawbacks and it's positives but i found this way was really benificial to me as i was learning how to do things and regularly needed a new VM :P

Something to note about what you have said, It is not recommended that you have VS on your production server.

Hope this helps

Truez

Comment: What you have suggested is with the help of TFS if I am not wrong. Is there any other solution where in I can do this without TFS. if no, I would like to know more in detail how the architecture works out after installing TFS.

Comment: Are you developers working on the same projects at the same time?

Comment: Yes. As of now, 2 developers are working inside the server for the same project. So they use the same solution file and work on the same database. Again we are setting up one more project and 2 more developers are assigned for this. Only 2 can login to the server, so we are looking for a work around. I would be happy if anyone could brief me about how the set up works in a big company so that we could also implement it here. I am taking care of administrative role and need to provide ideas to implement it

Comment: possibility of using VM's and this http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs I've never used this but have a good read around this and it might give you some idea

Comment: Hi.. We installed TFS in a diff server. How can I make the Sharepoint application in tfs and make it available in local virtual machine....It would be easy if i knw the procedures...